# No kill runs of Gamma stages?

Tags: sonic-adventure

In E-102 Gamma's stages in Sonic Adventure you start with a set amount of time and will lose a life if the time runs out, time is replenished by shooting enemies in the stage.

Is it possible to clear any or all of Gamma's stages with the time you are given at the start?

Comment: Most of Gamma's stages are completed by destroying a boss enemy (or a Sonic doll). Are these automatically disqualified, or are the boss enemies exempt from the restriction?

Comment: Well the question is more about completing the stage with the time you start with.

Comment: Is there a restriction for glitch abuse? Most runs on games are done using glitches and such.

Comment: I'm not making the nuzlocke challenge here, without glitches if possible I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took some time to watch a couple speedruns at https://www.speedrun.com/.

[The shortest time completing Gamma's Story](https://www.speedrun.com/run/dy4gv3yl), marked as "Glitched Route", uses glitches to run through the stages. You can see him shooting some enemies on the stage, but this isn't necessary at all, since he clear all stages under 3 minutes on each stage (3 minutes is the time given to clear a Gamma stage).

Since you asked on a comment for a non glitched run, if possible, I watched the best Gamma's story run marked as "Linear Route", just to find that, altough the person uses no glitches on the adventure fields to "skip" some story scenes, the person actually uses glitches during the stages to clear them faster. I watched some more just to find that, in the end, everyone end up using at least a glitch at Red Mountain stage.